# passing float numbers and strings to bash script

Tags: string, bash, floating-point

Possibly duplicated, but I could find the right solution.

I would like to pass the parameters to my bash script.

The script looks like this:

```
echo $1 echo $2
```

and I am running the code with the following command:

```
test.sh "string" 0.1
```

that is, I need to pass string and float numbers into the script. Those parameters are then applied to run Python code with some math simulations.

When I run the code, I got:

```
10e50 10e50
```

How can I properly pass the strings and floats to bash script?

Comment: That looks like python's representation, not bash's. bash doesn't handle floating point math so it's definitely not doing float conversions.

Comment: Why do you have both `echo` commands on the same line?

Comment: Does it really say `10e50`? Exponential notation should never have a number higher than `9` before `e`, so it should be `1e51`.

Comment: Show how the shell script passes the parameters to the Python script.

Comment: And show how the Python script parses the input.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you posted, it's somewhere else (as jordanm said, probably in the Python). I'd recommend going through the exercise of producing a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you're seeing. Make a copy of your current code, and start removing parts you think aren't relevant. If the problem vanishes, the bit you just removed *was* relevant, so put it back and try removing something else (or a smaller part). Often, once you've figured out where the core problem is, it'll be obvious *why* it happens.

Comment: Actually, you might be able to find the problem even faster by putting `set -x` in the shell script before the problem section. That'll print the commands that're being executed (after variables are expanded and things like that), so you can get a better idea where things are going weird.